# Laravel, eloquent way of Where In from other table

Tags: php, laravel

I have raw mysql queries as below, trying to get all the participant from **participants** table who is active (active = 1) and display the name and age of the participant from **users** table

```
SELECT name, age
FROM users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM participants
    WHERE active = 1
)
```

My question is, how do I convert this to laravel eloquent way?

```
User::whereIn(*how to insert Participant table here?*)->get();
```

Comment: You do this with relationships and a combination of [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) (to filter) and [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) (to eager load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL query you provided can be converted to Laravel's Eloquent ORM as follows:

```
$users = User::select('name', 'age')
    ->whereIn('id', function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query) {
        $query->select('user_id')
            ->from('participants')
            ->where('active', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

if you want to use join then you can do as follows:

```
$users = User::select('users.name', 'users.age')
    ->join('participants', 'users.id', '=', 'participants.user_id')
    ->where('participants.active', 1)
    ->get();
```

Using relationship and eager loading

```
$users = User::with('participants')
    ->select('name', 'age')
    ->whereHas('participants', function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) {
        $query->where('active', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

provided you have to create a relationship between user and participants

Comment: Why don't you use typed param for $query? So you know what functions you have in it? It is a Query Bilder from what I recal.  This type depends in the closure by the function in which it is pasted as param. with, where, whereIn, whereHas function have different types. It can be Relation, Builder or query builder.

Comment: Since this is a simple query I have not used typed param. The query is straightforward. Also I will update the answer with join which will be faster the doing sub query

Comment: It will not autocomplete the functions in the callback. whereIn has  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder. with has  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation. whereHas has  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder. There is no escuse in using "crap" code. All the code should be typed hinted if possible. This is valid also for laravel documentation. It is crappy if the type is not specified inline or in dock block.

Comment: Could you please specify the type in the above snippet

Comment: @marius-ciclistu i think that argument is missing the point, there is no consensus in the real world if closures should be typehinted. Most projects is a 50/50 if it's done. While for the question answered here, the subject is not about typehinting but about making an IN statement in the Eloquent ORM. This more than provides the information to do that.

Comment: @mrhn if an answered is accepted it should be the best it can be. So typehinted. If the majority are not using that, it is not an argument. @ Faizan I already pointed out in my previous comment for each function what type it receives.

Comment: @FaizanFayaz i forgot the where it has \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder